# How do I add a task to Things using the URI scheme?

Tags: iphone, url-scheme

The iPhone/iPad app 'Things' has a registered URI scheme. I know it exists:

```
things://
```

in Safari launches Things.

I'd like to use it from a web application.

Is there any documentation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've replied on the forums and posted an example there.  They plan to put a  documentation site up. Best to wait for that. But if you're impatient like me, here's the bookmarklet I'm successfully using on my iPhone:

```
javascript:window.location=%27things:add?title=%27+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+%27&notes=%27+encodeURIComponent(window.location)
```

Comment: Thank you! I can get back to my evil plans now! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ask the [developers](http://culturedcode.com/about/) for documentation (on [twitter](http://twitter.com/culturedcode) or in the [forums](http://culturedcode.com/forums/)).

Once you know the parameters you can use the URI just as a normal URL in your web app.

Answer (score 1):

I've been discussing the same thing on the forums, here:

http://culturedcode.com/forums/read.php?8,48550,49111#msg-49111

I've also asked on Twitter. So far our attempts haven't discovered the parameters, and there is no documentation. Hopefully we'll get a response soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is an email I received from them on Dec 22, 2010:

...

I wanted to let you know that we have now implemented a Things URI scheme that lets you add tasks to Things like so:

things:add?title=Buy%20milk&notes=Low%20fat&dueDate=2010-12-24

This will be released in our upcoming major releases for the iPhone (1.4) and iPad (1.7).

...